# Exception handling when dealing with user input for a beginner

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I have to do a little program based in a shop, I have to add new clients to the shop customer collection, new items to the shop stock, edit them etc, so I use user input(scanner) to create this new objects. I have all the methods I need for this already without exceptions.

I would like some simple java exception handling for when the user introduces a string were he is supposed to enter a integer or viceversa. 
For example if I'm executing a method to create a item for the shop and when I ask the user to introduce the stock(integer) the user types hello instead of a number the program crashes, I would like to handle the exception, show a error message, don't create the object and relaunch the item creation method from the beggining(or relaunch the submenu it was right before)

should I use try and catch? the method in try, when it fails catch throws message of error and relaunches the item creation menu? How should i do this? I've been searching and found a interesting method for integers here:
[Exception Handling for no user input in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41050343/exception-handling-for-no-user-input-in-java)

The problem is I don't know how I could handle possible exceptions for when introducing the ID for the user(which would be a string composed of 8 numbers and a letter like for example:  13234354A, so how could I show a error if a user introduces "sjadsjasdj" as a ID instead of something sort of realistic ) or some other things like handling exceptions for a few enum or boolean variables I use when creating this objects.

I've been looking in this site and searching google but I haven't found what I need or are more complex than what I understand with my little knowledge, also English is not my native language so my searches may be a little off.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: This is an ideal situation for input validation rather than exception handling.  It's easier to prevent the user from messing up, than handling unexpected input.

Comment: You mean the example in the link I sent? thanks for your reply!

Comment: Don't forget to select or provide an answer, if you have solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are reading the input just read in the the entire ID 123A for example and verify that each character is valid using for example Character.isDigit() and Character.isLetter(). With a 4 letter case

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        boolean flag = false;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(!flag) {
            String id = kb.next();//To get the next word
            flag = true;//by default its assumed to be valid input
            if(id.length() == 4) {
                for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    if(!Character.isDigit(id.charAt(i))) {
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }
                if(!Character.isLetter(id.charAt(3))) {
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
            else {
                flag = false;
            }
            System.out.println("ID is "+ (flag == true?"Valid":"Invalid"));
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
1234
ID is Invalid
123A
ID is Valid
```

You could throw your own error at the end if you want or just loop back to the beginning to take a new input.

Comment: Hi man, thanks for the example, where should I place the method to relaunch the user input if the flag is false for example? thanks

Comment: I have updated the solution to include a repeating loop.

Comment: I'll test this tomorrow. I assume I can adapt this to work when a user introduces a string instead of a int to keep the loop working.
Thanks man! Only have to figure out a good way to handle same problem with boolean and enums. Again, thanks!